# SQLite select average from one table and update average field from another table using trigger

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers, average

I have some problems with creating a trigger that will update values in a second table with average values from the first table. Since i am not very familiar with sqlite statements, maybe you guys can help me.

Here is my problem : i have one table table_1

[image: table 1 description]

and another table table_2

[image]

What i want is that table_2 "average_value" field to be updated with the average of values from table_1 that have the same field.

In this particular case resulting the aveage_value field in table 2 like this : 
5 - for field_a
8 - for field_b
0 - for field_c

Any suggestions will help me alot ! Thank You.

Comment: Any particular reason you need to write this to a table, rather than just exposing it in a VIEW?

Comment: Yes, i am using this in an android application and i need to retrieve the average_value from table_2 whenever a value from table_1 has been modified.

Comment: @DanRiza Your comment does not answer Declan_K's question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. To compute the average value of a specific field dynamically, use this query:

   ```
   SELECT AVG(value)
   FROM table_1
   WHERE field = 'field_a';
   ```
2. If you want instead a view that looks like your `table_2`, you can define it like this:

   ```
   CREATE VIEW view_2 AS
   SELECT field,
          AVG(value) AS average_value
   FROM table_1
   GROUP BY field;
   ```
3. If you really want `table_2` to be an actual table, you could compute the average values like this:

   ```
   UPDATE table_2
   SET average_value = (SELECT AVG(value)
                        FROM table_1
                        WHERE table_1.field = table_2.field);
   ```
4. If you want `table_2` to be an actual table, and want to update only those values that have changed, use a trigger like this:

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER update_average_value_after_insert
   AFTER INSERT ON table_1
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
       UPDATE table_2
       SET average_value = (SELECT AVG(value)
                            FROM table1
                            WHERE table1.field = NEW.field)
       WHERE field = NEW.field;
   END;
   ```

   (You also need similar triggers for `UPDATE` and `DELETE`.)

Comment: Thank you , the suggestion for point 4 is exactly what i needed. It woks perfectly